# Unable to view href link with email templates

Tags: java, html, email, notifications, freemarker

Hi, in my application I am trying to send notifications to mails. For this, I am using freemarker template.

So, in the template file I have used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Notification</title>
</head>
```

and I have given the URL as

```
<a target="_blank"
   style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none"
   href="**ADDED LINK HERE**">
    Activate your account
</a>
```

So, when I access this through gmail it is working fine.

But if send this template to yahoo mail I just can't see the href 
and if I open it in safari browser href is appended with **applewebdata://**.

So what is the problem. When am I going wrong?

Comment: href contains relative path or absolute?

Comment: I am using absolute url

Comment: Is there any problem with 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: only thing that comes to my mind is there might be some character which is not properly parsed

Comment: Atlast Found solution with help of this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986335/yahoo-disable-links-when-sent-from-smtpclient-net

Comment: but you already told you are using absolute path !?

Comment: i am using absolute path like www.example.com but its mandatory to add https:// or http:// before url to work it in yahoo mail

Comment: oh I thought you used "http://..." as well