# MimeMessage: Content sent different from content received

Tags: java, forms, mime-message

I have a strange behavior, while Im sending a mail :
This is my code :

```
mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
mailMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8" );
mailMessage.setContent(content, "text/html");       
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();       
transport.connect();        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage,mailMessage.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
```

This is what I send: (Only the form is concerned by the problem)

```
<form method="POST" action="localhost/Test/NotConnectedSetter.validateEmail" >
```

This is what I receive:

```
<form id="yui_3_16_0_1_1403504390037_61051" onsubmit="return theMainWindow.showFormWarning(this)" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

Lots of things are added (What I don't care) but my action is deleted.
I get the mail on yahoo (I'm not sure it's important, but who knows).
This is my only form in the page, I have no idea how this happens.
If anyone can help...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I forgot the "form" thing, since Yahoo will warn user to click on it. I will work with customers, I don't want them to be afraid by clicking on something for my website
Otherwise, I reproduced the same problem with  and the problem definitely came from yahoo!
Then, there is already a question this point.
Answer is here :
[yahoo disable links when sent from smtpclient .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986335/yahoo-disable-links-when-sent-from-smtpclient-net)
I tested it (short answer : add http/https to your url), and it works.